# Ajax load clicked link and fade out content?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a site where on load, the opacity of the body changes for a fade-in effect.

But when a link to another page of the site is clicked -- I want the content to "fade out", while have the new content load and fade in without the page refreshing. How do I achieve that? Is the below a step in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="brand_elements.html">Brand Elements</a></li>
    <li><a href="scenes.html">Scenes</a></li>
    <li><a href="live_action.html">Live Action</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
(function(){

    const body = document.querySelector("body");

    window.addEventListener("load", function(){
        body.classList.add("active");
    });

    var pageSelect = document.querySelectorAll("ul.menu li a");

    var changePage = function(page){

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

        ajax.open("GET", page, true);
        ajax.send();

        body.classList.remove("active");
    }

    for (page of pageSelect){
        page.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            changePage(this);
        });
    }

})();
```

Comment: cancel the click `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Hey! thanks for the suggestion. I tried that but the new page isn't loading. The content fades out but I'm not sure how to load the new page. I'm not trying to load the content into a div if that makes sense. Just load the page without refreshing.

Comment: Well I figured that is what your ajax call was doing.... You got to do something with the Ajax call to load the next page...